# Trying to get altair to save .png or .svg in the PythonAnywhere platform

Tags: selenium, pythonanywhere, altair

`foochart.save("foo.svg")` [requires Selenium and Chrome- or Gecko-driver.](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/saving_charts.html)

Was trying to set this up on my PythonAnywhere instance.  The guys there pointed me at this link [showing how to use Selenium inside PythonAnywhere](http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/).

Of note,  they say only install `v2 Selenium`.  I installed `selenium-2.53.6`

But looks like it does not work, and I'm suspicious that altair needs a newer version, as the failure reads like the `__init__` signature maybe changed:  `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'`

Can anyone advise on this?  I really am bummed that I cannot get altair and pythonAnywhere to cooperate -- the charts are so much nicer to generate when I don't have to use matplotlib,  but my server stuff runs inside PythonAnywhere.

the full code and stacktrace:

```
iris = data.iris()

foo = alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength',
    y='petalWidth',
    color='species'
)
foo.save("foo.png")
```

stacktrace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6aeea1cba6a3> in <module>
----> 1 foo.save("foo.png")

~/.virtualenvs/modern2019/lib/python3.6/site-packages/altair/vegalite/v2/api.py in save(self, fp, format, override_data_transformer, scale_factor, vegalite_version, vega_version, vegaembed_version, **kwargs)
    515         if override_data_transformer:
    516             with data_transformers.enable('default', max_rows=None):
--> 517                 result = save(**kwds)
    518         else:
    519             result = save(**kwds)

~/.virtualenvs/modern2019/lib/python3.6/site-packages/altair/utils/save.py in save(chart, fp, vega_version, vegaembed_version, format, mode, vegalite_version, embed_options, json_kwds, webdriver, scale_factor)
    100                                         vegaembed_version=vegaembed_version,
    101                                         webdriver=webdriver,
--> 102                                         scale_factor=scale_factor)
    103         if format == 'png':
    104             write_file_or_filename(fp, mimebundle['image/png'], mode='wb')

~/.virtualenvs/modern2019/lib/python3.6/site-packages/altair/utils/mimebundle.py in spec_to_mimebundle(spec, format, mode, vega_version, vegaembed_version, vegalite_version, **kwargs)
     54                               vega_version=vega_version,
     55                               vegaembed_version=vegaembed_version,
---> 56                               vegalite_version=vegalite_version, **kwargs)
     57         if format == 'png':
     58             render = base64.b64decode(render.split(',', 1)[1].encode())

~/.virtualenvs/modern2019/lib/python3.6/site-packages/altair/utils/headless.py in compile_spec(spec, format, mode, vega_version, vegaembed_version, vegalite_version, scale_factor, driver_timeout, webdriver)
    152             webdriver_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    153 
--> 154     driver = webdriver_class(options=webdriver_options)
    155 
    156     try:

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'
```

Answer (score 3):

Altair assumes you are using selenium version 3 or later. Update your selenium installation and the error should go away.